# Ghost config.js file

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

I m actually trying to create a simple blog using ghost, and I m facing a problem when starting in production envrionnement.

I m having the v0.7.1 and here's my config file (production part)

```
production: {
       url: 'http://<my-public-ip>',
       mail: {},
       database: {
           client: 'sqlite3',
           connection: {
               filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
           },
           debug: false
       },

       server: {
           host: '127.0.0.1',
           port: '2368'
       }
   }
```

The fact is that when I try to access my public IP on a browser, I cant get anything at all on the screen(404 not found), even if I try on the 2368 port.

My firewall rules are well set.

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

In the server object the host should be 0.0.0.0

server: {
           host: '0.0.0.0',
           port: '2368'
       }

Answer (score 0):

In the server object change the host .

```
host: '127.0.0.1', --> host: '0.0.0.0'
```

now start the ghost server by

```
npm start --production
```